# QT Creator:how to change the menu font size?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

I use QT Creator on surface pro4 and the font of menu is too small:
[image]

what should i do to change the font size?

version:5.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such option. You have to [modify the DPI scaling of windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html), which will make all "legacy" shell applications appear larger to compensate for the high DPI of the device.

If you don't want to modify the settings, you might want to try running creator with an `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2` env var or so.

Create a `startScaled.cmd` in creator's exe directory with the content:

```
@echo off 
set QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2
qtcreator.exe
```

And use this to start creator up-scaled.

Answer (score 8):

On linux mint for me, changing the desktop DPI scaling doesn't help with QT sidebar font in particular although most other things do scale.

The scale factor variable method does work though. Here's the script I used and just modify the installed menu shortcut for QtCreator to run it instead of directly running the qtcreator executable:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   #my_qtcreator.sh
   export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5
   /opt/Qt/qtcreator-4.2.2/bin/qtcreator
```

Comment: Thank you! A couple more variable options listed here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt

Answer (score 5):

I had the same nasty problem in Ubuntu , the solution is easy.

1. In the top left menu , choose `Tools > Options > Environment`
2. Mark the checkbox that says **"Enable high DPL scaling"**
3. Restart and it should work

Comment: its DPI Dots Per Inch.  Disabling this helps if you want to make the font smaller.  In QT Designer the accepted answer works, but in Creator setting QT_SCALE_FACTOR less than 1 messes everything up.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running on Linux Fedora 27/Gnome/Wayland on a 4K monitor (3840 x 2160).  A microscope was nearly necessary to read most of Qt Creator's window panes.

This fixed it for me:

Create `qtcreator` in an executable file in my path with this content:

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 ~/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 &
```

An alias would do just as well.  It is not necessary to export any environment variables.  This uses the shell syntax which sets an environment variable only for the process to be created.  I have Qt installed in my directory instead of system-wide.

I got the environment variable from @joelostblom's comment on the answer [here, above/below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959458/198536) pointing to [this Qt reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt).

With Gnome already set to scale by 200%, a try of `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2` resulted in ridiculously large text.  But using *QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR* and scaling by one was enough of a nudge for it to react properly to Gnome's settings.

Comment: You are probably seeing scaling issues because Qt defaults to the X backend on Gnome. Gnome on Wayland is currently blackisted by the Qt Wayland plugin due to [a bug in mutter](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/199). The bug has been fixed now, but the blacklist can't be removed until major distros upgrade to newer versions of Gnome. You can force Qt to use Wayland on gnome by setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` in the environment.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users pro anno 2024:

1. Install Qt Creator with apt.
2. On my machine qtcreator.desktop file is located in `/usr/share/applications` and it's name is `org.qt-project.qtcreator.desktop`
3. Edit file, change line `Exec=qtcreator %F` to: `Exec=env QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5 qtcreator %F` you may need to be super user for this. Where 1.5 is a scale you may choose whatever you need. Save file.
4. As super user run `update-desktop-database`. Now it will start with required scale factor.