# QT creator 4.7.4 VS QT creator 4.15.0 : size of MENU icons

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have QT creator 4.7.4 and  QT creator 4.15.0 **size of MENU icons are too large in QT creator 4.15.0**.
Please see the attached image, if I press **file button** in MENU bar, size of drop down menu is too large.

I am using windows 10.

Please suggest, How to reduce this size of Menu ICON in QT creator 4.15.0 ?

QT creator 4.15.0 if I press **file button** in MENU bar :--
[image: QT creator 4.15.0]

QT creator 4.7.4 if I press **file button** in MENU bar :--
[image: QT creator 4.7.4]

This is my font size in QT creator 4.15.0 :--
[image: Font size : QT creator 4.15.0]

Comment: It looks like **all** your fonts are larger in the newer version. Is there a preference to change font size(s) globally?

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the font size ..?

Comment: I don't know, was just suggesting you could check the options/preferences. Also, search for similar questions first, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096165/qt-creatorhow-to-change-the-menu-font-size), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366595/how-to-reset-the-size-of-the-qts-window-font)